# Future Xcode project

Tags: xcode

I see this error while opening the project in Xcode (Version 10.1 (10B61)) on OSX Mojave (Version 10.14).

Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SpotlightAPI/Introduction/Intro.html

[image: Photo]

Comment: The message seems to tell you exactly what to do, so what's your question?

Comment: @Caleb yes, it does seem obvious looking at the error. But did you check out the link provided? and the Xcode version (Version 10.1 (10B61)) is not too old.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your XCode in order to open the project file.

Comment: yes, it does seem obvious looking at the error. But did you check out the link provided? and the Xcode version (Version 10.1 (10B61)) is not too old

Answer (score 1):

> yes, it does seem obvious looking at the error. But did you check out the link provided? and the Xcode version (Version 10.1 (10B61)) is not too old

Despite the message, it looks like the problem is that the project is so old that current versions of Xcode don't recognize the project file format. The project file format stabilized at some point along the way so that, say, Xcode 10.x, 9.x, and maybe older versions can all work with the same file. But you're looking at a version of the Spotlight API from 2005, which means the sample projects were probably created with Xcode 2.0 or thereabout.

The Spotlight API that you're looking at is part of [Apple's documentation archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/navigation/), which contains old documentation that's no longer being maintained, so there's no reason to expect the sample projects to work with current Xcode versions. Your best bet is to look instead at [the current Spotlight documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/spotlight?language=objc).